# multi statement table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
     UserName  Question_ID  Answer
      Tom       Q001           D
      Wendy     Q009           A
      Eddy      Q089           C
      David     Q001           C
      Eve       Q001           D
      Paul      Q001           A
      Sam       Q001           B
      Tom       Q002           B
      Tom       Q003           C
```

I want to create multi statement tabled valued function.

Let Question_id as input,
I want to create table shows 
question_id, answer, number of answers, and percentages of answers

For example (input: Question_id = Q001)

The output will be

```
   Question_ID Answer Total Percentage
    Q001          A      1       20
    Q001          B      1       20
    Q001          C      1       20
    Q001          D      2       40
```

## I have created function

```
    create function [dbo].[QuestionFrequency]
    (
    @question_id varchar(10)    
    )

    Returns @frequency table (question_id varchar(10), answer varchar(10))
    As 
    begin

    insert @frequency (question_id, answer)
    select question_Id, Answer from questions where @question_id = Question_id
    return 
    end
```

it shows me the out put

```
Question_ID     Answer
Q001           D
Q001           C
Q001           D
Q001           A
Q001           B
```

What should i do to count the total and percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    q.Question_ID, q.Answer,
    count(*) as Total,
    count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from questions as t where t.Question_ID = @question_id) as [Percentage]
from questions as q
where q.Question_ID= @question_id
group by q.Question_ID, q.Answer
```

Comment: Thanks, but still cannot get the percentage :)

Comment: i just changed to
 count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from questions as t where....
it works :D thanks buddy

Comment: @DongminWon yep, missed that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
Question_ID,
Answer,
COUNT(*) TotaL_Answers,
(COUNT(*) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(2),(select COUNT(*) from TABLE_NAME where Question_ID= 'Q001')))*100 'Percent'
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Question_ID= 'Q001'
GROUP BY Question_ID, Answer
```

Comment: you have to add where clause to subquery

Comment: Oh Yes, I missed that..Thanks.